# How to find the highest and second highest entry in SQL in a single query using `GROUP BY`?

Tags: sql, database

Let this be the table that is provided.

| PID | TID | Type | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | B | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | A | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | B | 5 |

I want to write a query to get an output like this.

| PID | TID | Type | Max_Freq_1 | Max_Freq_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | B | 3 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | A | 4 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | B | 5 | NULL |

That is, given a combination of `PID`, `TID`, `Type`, what is the highest and second-highest frequency? If there aren't a sufficient number of entries in the table, then put second highest as  `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

If your database can use the window functions, then the top 2 Freq can be calculated via the DENSE_RANK function.

```
SELECT PID, TID, Type
, MAX(CASE WHEN Rnk = 1 THEN Freq END) AS Max_Freq_1
, MAX(CASE WHEN Rnk = 2 THEN Freq END) AS Max_Freq_2
FROM
(
    SELECT PID, TID, Type, Freq
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PID, TID, Type ORDER BY Freq DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM YourTable t
) q
GROUP BY PID, TID, Type
ORDER BY PID, TID, Type
```

| pid | tid | type | max_freq_1 | max_freq_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | B | 3 | *null* |
| 1 | 2 | A | 4 | *null* |
| 1 | 2 | B | 5 | *null* |

If ROW_NUMBER isn't available, then try this.

```
SELECT PID, TID, Type
, MAX(CASE WHEN Rnk = 1 THEN Freq END) AS Max_Freq_1
, MAX(CASE WHEN Rnk = 2 THEN Freq END) AS Max_Freq_2
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.PID, t1.TID, t1.Type, t1.Freq
    , COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Freq) AS Rnk
    FROM YourTable t1
    LEFT JOIN YourTable t2 
      ON t2.PID = t1.PID
     AND t2.TID = t1.TID
     AND t2.Type = t1.Type
     AND t2.Freq >= t1.Freq
    GROUP BY t1.PID, t1.TID, t1.Type, t1.Freq
) q
GROUP BY PID, TID, Type
ORDER BY PID, TID, Type
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=75a2cff6b700a23ec2311a6d68935cad)*

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with on PostgreSQL. Using the window function like row_number is the easiest way to get the result you want.

```
with t as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by pid, tid, "type" order by freq desc) as r 
    from test_so 
) select pid, tid, "type", max(case when r = 1 then freq end) as "highest", max(case when r = 2 then freq end) as "second_highest" 
    from t 
    group by pid, tid, "type"
```

[image: postgres resultset image]